# ¿Es posible usar un html para dos urls distintas en Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Quiero usar el mismo html para dos rutas distintas, pero ocultando ciertos elementos para una u otra. ¿Es posible?

Por ejemplo tengo:

```
share: {
  url: '/administration/share_view',
  templateUrl: 'administration/copy/share_view.html',
  controller: 'DialogDemoCtrl',
  name: 'tableShare'
},
publish: {
  url: '/administration/publish_view',
  templateUrl: 'administration/copy/share_view.html',
  controller: 'DialogDemoCtrl',
  name: 'tablePublish'
}
```

y este es el html

```
  <div class="copy-container" ng-controller="DialogDemoCtrl as DialogDemoCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt10">
    <p class="bold fs16" ng-if="location.path() != '/tablePublish'">Lista de usuarios con acceso a la ficha</p>
    <p class="bold fs16">¿A quiénes desea notificar de la publicación?</p>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Seleccionado</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th ng-if="location.path() != '/tablePublish'">Ultimo envio</th>
        <th ng-if="location.path() != '/tablePublish'">Acciones</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ml20">
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td ng-if="location.path() != '/tablePublish'"></td>
        <td ng-if="location.path() != '/tablePublish'">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-pacificblue mr5 p5 p0">Reenviar</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-pacificblue mr5 p5 p0">Remover</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  {{location.path()}}

  <div class="row text-right">
    <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="location.path() != '/tablePublish'">Enviar a todos los seleccionados</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger">Publicar y notificar a los seleccionados</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Los elementos se ocultan, pero no se muestran en la ruta que deseo que aparezcan.

Comment: y que resultado obtuviste en tu codigo?

Comment: los elementos se ocultan, pero no se muestran en la ruta que deseo que aparezcan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo, tu tienes el mismo codigo html y el mismo `controller` pero hay 2 tipos de acciones. Por lo tanto te recomiendo que todo esto lo evalues desde tu `controller`

```
.controller('DialogDemoCtrl', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.viewPublish = false;
    if($location.path() == '/administration/publish_view'){  
        $scope.viewPublish = true;
    }
})
```

Y en tu vista :

```
 <th ng-show="!viewPublish">Ultimo envio</th>
 <th ng-show="viewPublish">Acciones</th>
```

En este caso particular :

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="ml20">
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td ng-show="viewPublish"></td>
  <td ng-show="viewPublish">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-pacificblue mr5 p5 p0">Reenviar</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-pacificblue mr5 p5 p0">Remover</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: gracias! solo tuve que cambiar 'if($location.path() == '/tablePublish')' por 'if($location.path() == '/administration/publish_view')' y funciono !

Comment: @pasasalron perfecto, recuerda marcar como correcta si resolvio tu problema :D

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que podrías utilizar la clausula `resolve` a la hora de declarar las diferentes vistas, por lo que la definición de tus rutas quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
share: {
  url: '/administration/share_view',
  templateUrl: 'administration/copy/share_view.html',
  controller: 'DialogDemoCtrl',
  name: 'tableShare',
  resolve: {
            route: 'tableShare'
        }
},
publish: {
  url: '/administration/publish_view',
  templateUrl: 'administration/copy/share_view.html',
  controller: 'DialogDemoCtrl',
  name: 'tablePublish',
  resolve: {
            route: 'tablePublish'
        }
}
```

Y desde tu controller podrías utilizar la dependencia 'route' de la siguiente manera:

```
.controller('DialogDemoCtrl', function($scope, route){
    $scope.tablePublish= false;
    if(route == 'tablePublish'){  
        $scope.tablePublish = true;
    }
})
```

Dado el controller, la vista quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<p class="bold fs16" ng-if="tablePublish">Lista de usuarios con acceso a la ficha</p>
```